# static lib global value got reset after call from DLL

Tags: c, visual-c++, windows-ce

I have c++ libary in wince 6.0, There is some global variable. that libary has been linked with DLL which is c++. when i exected application and called DLL. first its intilized all global variable  of static libary but when control come back to DLL to static lib. Its reset all glbal value. Do anyone have idea about that.

Comment: Have you linked only the one DLL to the static lib or are other DLLs or EXE also linked to the static lib?

Comment: @ben with two DLL, I have added LIB

Answer (score 0):

If you have linked two DLLs with the static library, this means that you have two copies of all the code and variables in the library.

To solve this issue you should convert the static library into a DLL. This can be done with a simple project consisting of a `module.def` file, and a linker call.

Then instead of linking your DLLs with the static library, link them with your DLL.

Alternatively, instead of having two dlls, combine the project to have a single DLL.

Note that it can be OK to link two modules with the same static library, provided that you understand and accept that the data will NOT be shared.

Comment: thanks its working now. we are using one lib only for one dll.